# jquery fade out content

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fade out the part of the user form to load the next form step (by fading in).  But when I click submit, it submits the form, and does not fade out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(input, name) {
        if( form['register'] = true ) {
            $("#step1").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    }

<form id="register" name="register" method="post" action="">
    <div id="step1" class="step1">
        form here...
        ...
        <input type="submit" 
               name="next" 
               id="next" 
               value="Continue" 
               disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple submit buttons in your form? Why not have *one* submit button, and next/previous links within fieldsets to move to the next/previous 'page'? Also, show your code. And a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) (remember [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).)

Comment: You should probably give more insight into how the rest of this form works, what causes your user to be able to click the submit button when it is disabled? How is validate being called?

Comment: the button is initially disabled so when the page loads, they have to fill in the fields before continuing.  validate is called on blur for the text fields

Comment: @David Thomas - so keep the next/previous button out of the div so that it is static, and just use that as navigation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent your form from submitting to allow your fades to take place:

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#step1").fadeOut("slow");
  });
});
```

*But as a suggestion, you should use buttons to allow the user to navigate back and forward between steps, and use the submit button for the last step only.*

Comment: perfect; thanks!  so change the type of the submit button, and just add a "onclick" attribute?

Comment: so if i change the form type to button instead of submit, how would this code change?

Comment: If you use a form button, you don't need to prevent the submit, instead you need to call a function to do the fade or bind a click to the button! Ex. for onclick: <input type="button" onclick="fadeToNextStep();" value="continue to step 2">

Answer (score 1):

> "But when I click submit, it submits the form, and does not fade out."

That line makes me believe that you want the div to hide, at the moment you submit the form. Here is how you would go about doing that:

```
//Select #register, bind a 'submit'-event.
$('#register').on('submit', function(e){

  //This next line will prevent the form from being submitted.
  e.preventDefault();

  //Fade out the #step1.
  $('#step1').fadeOut('slow');

});
```